# Improving select/3 in ProLog

Tags: select, prolog

I would like to improve *select/3* in prolog by selecting multiple elements in a given list (instead of one). For example, if I select *X = 1* and *Y = 2* in this list, *[1,2,3]*, then the result will be *[3]*.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select_pair(X,Y,[X|Xs],Xs) :- member(Y,Xs).
select_pair(X,Y,[H|T1],[H|T2]) :- select_pair(X,Y,T1,T2).
```

The result is:

```
?- select_pair(X,Y,[1,2,3],Zs).
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Zs = [2, 3] ;
X = 1,
Y = 3,
Zs = [2, 3] ;
X = 2,
Y = 3,
Zs = [1, 3] ;
```

However, the correct results should be Zs = [3], [2], [1], respectfully. I know I have to somehow intersect these two values together; therefore, here's the intersect method:

```
intersect([],M,[]).
intersect([X|L],M,[X|I]) :- member(X,M), intersect(L,M,I).
intersect([X|L],M,I) :- \+ member(X,M), intersect(L,M,I).
```

I think I have to somehow use the intersect method instead of *member* method.

May someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close! Use `select/3` instead of `member/2`:

```
select_pair(X, Y, [X|Xs], Result) :- select(Y, Xs, Result).
select_pair(X, Y, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :- select_pair(X,Y,T1,T2). % unmodified

?- select_pair(X, Y, [1,2,3], Z).
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = [3] ;
X = 1,
Y = 3,
Z = [2] ;
X = 2,
Y = 3,
Z = [1] ;
false.
```

For comparison I'd be tempted to code it like this:

```
select_pair(X, Y, In, Out) :- 
  select(X, In, Mid), select(Y, Mid, Out).
```

This actually generates permutations rather than combinations though, which I infer is not what you want.

I don't think you're going to be able to get intersect to work for this problem. Intuitively, what you'd like to do is something like this:

```
select_pair(X, Y, In, Out) :- intersection([X,Y], Out, In).
```

The problem is that neither `intersect/3` above or the SWI built-in `intersection/3` will generate like that. It makes sense why they wouldn't: there's no way to know the contents of the two sets based on their intersection because that data simply doesn't survive.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel Lyons. This was extremely helpful!

Comment: No problem, hope you enjoy using Prolog. :)